# How does this card trick work?

Tags: arithmetic

Pick a card from the deck and keep it secret.
Double the face value of the card (aces = 1, jacks = 11, queens = 12, and kings = 13).
Add 3 to the result.
Multiply this by 5.
Add 1 if the card is a club, 2 if it is a diamond, 3 if it is a heart, and 4 if it is a spade.
Ask them to tell you their number.

To predict the card, subtract 15 from the final total. The right digit of the answer represents the suit of the card (1 = club, 2 = diamond, 3 = heart, 4 = spade). The left digit or digits is the number value of the card. For example, if their result is 83, the card is the 8 of hearts. If the result is 134, the card is the king of spades.
Can you figure out how this trick works?

Thank you, 
Liz

Comment: It's not a trick. It's just a bijection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the face value $f$ and the suit value $s$.

- You start with $f$
- Double it to $2f$
- Add three to give $2f+3$
- Multiply by five to give $10f+15$
- Add the suit value to give $10f+s+15$
- Subtract fifteen to give $10f+s$

Since $1 \le s \le 4$ the right hand digit is $s$ and the tens' digit (and perhaps hundreds' digit) show $f$.

Comment: We can't make edits less than 6 char, but I think you mistyped r as s, or s as r ?

Comment: @Kalissar - yes - thank you